# Weird UI and missing fonts in some applications

Tags: fonts, gui

I've got a dual boot Ubuntu machine for at least a year now and I have these problems since the beginning. In some applications fonts are not showing up right and the frames sometimes start up very small (before I enlarge them).

An example is shown below in the application GPick:

[image: Weird UI in GPick]

Another application that shows this behaviour is my password manager Enpass:

[image: Weird UI in Enpass]

The weird behaviour has been there since the beginning of this dual boot. It only shows in certain applications. Other apps show just fine. I believe I started with Ubuntu 15 but now I'm running Ubuntu 17.10. I hope any of you have a suggestion.

Comment: Never found out what the issue was and how to fix it properly. Ended up installing a fresh Ubuntu and the problem was fixed.